# Problems with bar plot style and size

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make my plot look like the one in the screenshot. Same colors, same style and position of the legends and the dotted grid in the background!

[image]

One more bar will be added, though

Ideally it would look something like this(3 bars only):

[image]

```
 \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{curlyblue}{RGB}{39,26,115}
\definecolor{curlygreen}{RGB}{48,172,140}   
\pgfplotsset{width=9cm,compat=1.8}
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list={
    {black,fill=curlyblue,mark=none},
{black,fill=curlygreen,mark=none},
{black,fill=yellow,mark=none},
}, }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=]
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.09,
    legend style={at={(0.75,0.95)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=1},
    ylabel={RMSE},
    symbolic x coords={50,100,150,200,250},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]


\addplot coordinates {(50,0.9359) (100,0.9351) (150,0.9361) (200,0.9376) (250,0.9386) };
\addplot coordinates {(50,0.9324) (100,0.9294) (150,0.9291) (200,0.9290) (250,0.9289) };
\addplot coordinates {(50,0.9297) (100,0.9281) (150,0.9280) (200,0.9280) (250,0.9280) };
\legend{Cosine,Pearson,PearsonBL}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also tried this but it does not work either:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    A,  B,  C,  D
    50,  0.9359, 0.9324, 0.9297
    100, 0.9351, 0.9294, 0.9281
    150, 0.9361, 0.9291, 0.9280
    200, 0.9376, 0.9290, 0.9280
    250, 0.9386, 0.9289, 0.9280
%   300, 0.9359, 0.9359, 0.9359
%   350, 0.9359, 0.9359, 0.9359
%   350, 0.9359, 0.9359, 0.9359 
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,]{data.csv}\datatable

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=11cm,
    ybar,
    bar width=7pt,
    xlabel={},
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{A},
    ymajorgrids,
    legend pos=north west
    ]
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=B]{\datatable};
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=C]{\datatable};
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=D]{\datatable};
    \legend{Cosine, Pearson, PearsonBL}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

HERE ARE THE TRUE COORDINATES:

```
\addplot[black,fill=blue1] coordinates {
(50,0.9359) (100,0.9351) (150,0.9361) (200,0.9376) (250,0.9386) (300,0.9391) (350,0.9393) (400,0.9395)
  };
   \addlegendentry{Bla0}
\addplot[black,fill=red1] coordinates {


(50,0.9324) (100,0.9294) (150,0.9291) (200,0.9290) (250,0.9289) (300,0.9289) (350,0.9289) (400,0.9289)};
\addlegendentry{Bla1}

\addplot[black,fill=gray1] coordinates {
                    (50,0.9297) (100,0.9281) (150,0.9280) (200,0.928) (250,0.928) (300,0.928) (350,0.928) (400,0.9280)
                };
    \addlegendentry{Bla2}
```

Comment: Could you please add some clarifications to your question about what exactly your problem is: Is it the position and style of the legend, is ist the colors, is it the numbers that appear above the bars, is it the y-axis labels, is it the dotted grid in the background...?

Comment: I want to make my plot look like the one in the screenshot. Same colors, same style and position of the legends and the dooted grid in the background!

Comment: So, basically, everything, I mentioned. Since your screenshot of the desired output only shows two sets of bars, (=two colors), what's the desired color of the third set?

Comment: A gray good be awesome! Or whatever one you consider that matches the triplet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the following is closer to what you wanted to achieve:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%% Define the colors used for the bars %%
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,143}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{128,0,0}   
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\pgfplotsset{width=9cm,compat=1.8}


%% Set up for the bar chart, mostly unchanged despite of colors %%
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={
                 /pgfplots/cycle list={
                     {black,fill=myblue,mark=none},
                     {black,fill=myred,mark=none},
                     {black,fill=mygray,mark=none},
             }, }}


%% Adding the dotted grid %%
\pgfplotsset{grid style = {
                 dash pattern = on 0.05mm off 1mm,
                 line cap = round,
                 black,
                 line width = 0.5pt
             }}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    %% related to legend, draw=none removes the border, anchor= north east places legend in upper right corner%%
    legend style={draw=none,at={(1,1)},anchor=north east,legend columns=1},
    legend cell align={left},
    %% style of y axis labels, precision=3 adds a third decimal place, fixed zerofill adds otherwise missing zeros (e.g. 0.93 vs. 0.930)%%
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=3,fixed zerofill},
    ylabel={RMSE},
    %% ymax makes sure that the legend does not overlap with the blue 250 bar
    ymax=0.941, 
    %% adds sme horizontal white space between the left- and right-most bar and hte corresponding y axis%%
    enlarge x limits=0.15,
    %% adds the grid that we defined earlier%%
    grid,
    %% makes sure that the ticks of the upper x axis stay inside the plot
    xtick align=inside
    ]


\addplot coordinates {(50,0.9359) (100,0.9351) (150,0.9361) (200,0.9376) (250,0.9386) };
\addplot coordinates {(50,0.9324) (100,0.9294) (150,0.9291) (200,0.9290) (250,0.9289) };
\addplot coordinates {(50,0.9297) (100,0.9281) (150,0.9280) (200,0.9280) (250,0.9280) };
\legend{Cosine,Pearson,PearsonBL}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Changes I have done in comparison to the original code:

- **Color of the bars:**
  In order to add the desired colors to the bars, I have changed the origonal `\definecolor` commands to match the colors in the screenshot. I have also added a third, gray color for the third set of bars.
- **Dotted grid**:
  The code for the dotted grid is borrowed from Jake's answer to [Change grid line dash pattern such that grid intersections look uniform](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96706/134144)
- **Legend style**: To remove the box around the legend, I have used the `draw=none`option. To place the legend in the upper right corner, I have used `anchor=north east` and to left align the legend entries, I have used `legend cell align={left}`. (Inspiration for these options came from Harry49's answer to [How to align the content of the legend to the left instead of default centre?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317336/134144) and from Matthew Leingang's answer to [Removing legend box (border) in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7011/134144)). I have also added `y max` in order to prevent the legend from overlapping with the large blue bar of the rightmost set.
- **Number format of y axis**: To change the number format of the y axis to include an additional decimal place, I have used `y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=3,fixed zerofill},` that was inspired by Jake's answer to [pgfplots - number format on axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96347/134144). If you prefer `0.930` being displayed without the trailing `0`(as in `0.93`), simply remove `fixed zerofill`.
- **Horizontal white space**: To add some horizontal white space between the leftmost and the rigtmost column and theis respective y axis, I have used `enlarge x limits=0.15,` as suggested by Jake in their answer to [Insert space between axis and plot in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19519/134144).
- **Position of upper x axis ticks**: In order to place the ticks of the upper x axis below the axis (inside of the plot)  instead of above, I have added `xtick align=inside` as shown by Jake in the answer to [Pgfplots ybar option draws tickmarks outside the plot area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184356/134144).
- **Numbers above bars**: Lastly, I have removed `nodes near coords` to get rid of the numbers that were displayes above the corresponding bars.

---

Here is the adjsted MWE for your actual data. I have adjusted the color names to match the definitions, changed the values of `ymax` and `enlarge x limits` and added added `bar width=5pt,` to prevent the individual sets of bars from overlapping:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%% Define the colors used for the bars %%
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,143}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{128,0,0}   
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{128,128,128}

\pgfplotsset{width=9cm,compat=1.8}


%% Adding the dotted grid %%
\pgfplotsset{grid style = {
                 dash pattern = on 0.05mm off 1mm,
                 line cap = round,
                 black,
                 line width = 0.5pt
             }}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    bar width=5pt,
    %% related to legend, draw=none removes the border, anchor= north east places legend in upper right corner%%
    legend style={draw=none,at={(1,1)},anchor=north east,legend columns=1},
    legend cell align={left},
    %% style of y axis labels, precision=3 adds a third decimal place, fixed zerofill adds otherwise missing zeros (e.g. 0.93 vs. 0.930)%%
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=3,fixed zerofill},
    ylabel={RMSE},
    %% ymax makes sure that the legend does not overlap with the blue 250 bar
    ymax=0.943, 
    %% adds sme horizontal white space between the left- and right-most bar and hte corresponding y axis%%
    enlarge x limits=0.1,
    %% adds the grid that we defined earlier%%
    grid,
    %% makes sure that the ticks of the upper x axis stay inside the plot
    xtick align=inside
    ]


\addplot[black,fill=myblue] coordinates {
        (50,0.9359) (100,0.9351) (150,0.9361) (200,0.9376) (250,0.9386) (300,0.9391) (350,0.9393) (400,0.9395)};
   \addlegendentry{Bla0}

\addplot[black,fill=myred] coordinates {
        (50,0.9324) (100,0.9294) (150,0.9291) (200,0.9290) (250,0.9289) (300,0.9289) (350,0.9289) (400,0.9289)};
\addlegendentry{Bla1}

\addplot[black,fill=mygray] coordinates {
        (50,0.9297) (100,0.9281) (150,0.9280) (200,0.928) (250,0.928) (300,0.928) (350,0.928) (400,0.9280)};
\addlegendentry{Bla2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just in case , for the labels: ` \pgfplotsset{legend image code/.code={\draw [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);},}`

Comment: @NaveganTeX: I have edited my answer to include an annotated, slightly changed MWE as well as some additional explanation. I hope this helps if you want to do some further adjustments.

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @NaveganTeX: You're welcome. For fun, I have added another, slightly edited MWE that includes the real coordinates (that I did not see before) from your question.